# How do I change the ForeColor of a GroupBox without having that color applied to every child control as well?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to change the group box text to a specific color without changing the color of what is inside the group box.

The following code sets the `ForeColor` of the `GroupBox` to pink but this settings cascades to all the child controls as well:

```
groupbox.ForeColor = Color.Pink
```

How do I change the `ForeColor` of a `GroupBox` without having that color applied to every child control as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate through all the controls in the GroupBox and set their respective ForeColor properties:

```
groupBox1.ForeColor = Color.Pink;
foreach (Control ctl in groupBox1.Controls) {
    ctl.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
}
```

Comment: @Andrew, no it doesn't, any children of child controls which are themselves containers will "inherit" the ForeColor property from their immediate parent, not from the GroupBox

Comment: Due note that this assumes all child controls have a foreground color of `SystemColors.ControlText`. While this may be true 99% of the time, in special cases, you may want to first go through the child controls and save their foreground colors in a IDictionary<Control, Color> to ensure they keep their original forecolors.

Answer (score 0):

```
form_load()
{
    ...
    foreach (Control ctl in groupbox.Controls) 
    {
        // load color value from parent and explicitly set it to control level
        ctl.ForeColor = ctl.ForeColor;
    }
    ...
}


some_click()
{
    groupbox.ForeColor = Color.Pink;
}

someother_click()
{
    groupbox.ForeColor = Color.Green; 
}
```

Color is not set for childcontrol until it done explicitly, and when childcontrol color requested it taken from the parent. Changing parent's color will refresh all it's content and childcontrol will take color from the parent.

If you set (explicitly) child color then child will not "asking" parent.

Child color can be set in designer too, but if color is the same as parent's color, designer will reduce this setting. Code in load event force child to have own color.